# Alliterative to maxlength attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the site I'm working on we have an interactive keyboard for touch screens. It looks great and works fantastic, except when we want to have a max char count on a field.

The maxlength property doesn't want to work because of how the keyboard takes away the focus of the input and inserts into the inputs.

Is there another way to limit what people can type in input fields without using the maxlength property?

I've done some searching on the web and from everything I've looked at everyone always points to just using maxlength.

I have tried a few things, like creating a substing

```
$('.input').val().substring(9);
```

but the user can still type in the field things are just halted when grabbing the value.

I have also tried

```
return false;
```

inside an if statement when they hit the max char count, but this just freezes my page up and the user can no longer interact with the screen.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Add a JS function that counts the characters every time one is added.  Once they go over by one, truncate the field by one character.  No warning, no loss of focus.

Comment: Are you saying that while the user is typing, the characters don't go into the text field until the user is finished?

Comment: Are `keyup` events triggered as the user types, or not until they're done?

Comment: @Barmar characters are being entered as they type, but there is no keyup or keydown events. It's all controlled via the on screen keyboard.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, I'm already counting the characters, how would I go about truncating them?

Comment: With the same `substring` statement you have in your question.

Comment: @isherwood, I don't think I'm understanding quite right. When I use that substring statement it only returns a few characters...and none of the ones I need to show up.

Comment: Just grab the entire contents of the box, less one character, then set the vale of the box on that substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each character, do something like this:

```
$('.input').val( $(this).val().substring(0,100) );
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/p05Lfwv2/)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't putting the substring inside the val of the input.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a function to truncate the input after the specified number of chars:

```
function truncateInput(inputElement, maxLength) {
    inputElement = $(inputElement);
    inputElement.on("change",function() {
        var val = inputElement.val();
        val = val.substr(0,maxLength - 1);
        inputElement.val(val);
    });
}
```

Pass that the jQuery selector **string** (i.e. `'#element'` not `$('#element')` and the maximum length, and it'll add the listeners to do this for you.